# Rails4 - How to set default selection for f.date_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, erb

I have the following in my sign up form.
How to set the selected attribute of option tag?

```
 <div>
  <%= f.label :date_of_birth, :class=>'singleline' %>
  <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, { :start_year => 1920, :end_year => 2010 }, :class => 'form-control date-select datetest' %>
  </div>
```

How to make the year 1985 to be selected instead of 1920?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a form modelled around an object, the default value depends on the object referenced by the form. Therefore, if the default value should be `1920`, you need to assign this value to the object.

Assuming the object passed to `form_for` is `@user`, when you initialize it set the attribute

```
def new
  @user = User.new(date_of_birth: 1985)
end
```

instead of simply

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

if the field is a date, then set the value to the date you want.

```
def new
  @user = User.new(date_of_birth: Date.parse("1985-01-01"))
end
```